# react-router-redux: history.listen is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I have a React/Redux app with `react-router-redux`. With Webpack everything is fine. But, when I use Bower with `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-redux/4.0.5/ReactRouterRedux.js` (4.0.5 is the most recent version and I have `react-router` 2.4.1), I have the following error:

> history.listen is not a function

here is my code

```
var syncHistoryWithStore = ReactRouterRedux.syncHistoryWithStore;
var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;
var history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
console.log(history); 

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

it logs

> History > {length: 2, state: Object, scrollRestoration: "auto"}

and you can see that the property `listen` is missing.

However, when I go into the code of `syncHistoryWithStore`, the returned object is an object with a lot of properties including listen.

> Object {**v2_compatible**: true, ..., listen}

So, it looks like the `Object` is somehow converted to a `Symbol` (`History`) but I don't know why and how.

Comment: could you try to restore it here: https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/r9dbgsjj/. Also just as a wild guess, try changing the var's name from history to something else.

Comment: Heya, did you get to solve that one? I stumbled into the same thing.. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, I did not :/